# How to find values and create an array of them in VB excel?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am having problems with this. I have to find non blank cells in one `column ("E")` and put them in an array and then list that array. I tried this, but the array is not filled properly

```
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim X() As String

    k = 0
    dimX = Application.CountA(Range("E2:E2498")) 
    ReDim X(1 To dimX)

    For i = 2 To 2498
     If IsEmpty(Cells(i, "E")) Then
      k = k + 1
      X(k) = Cells(i, "E").Value
     End If
    Next i
```

Comment: what sort of array, single dimesion string array, 2D array etc? And do you have formula cells and/or constants (text strings or hardcoded numbers) in column E?

Comment: Having now run your code (doh) strike my first question .... your code as is above will run on both formulae/values and return the values (as my code does below)

Answer (score 3):

I've rewritten this code to optimixe the speed namely:

- testing whether there are any column E entries up front
- using `SpecialCells` to immediately return ranges of formulae and constants
- using variant arrays to work through each area of the used portion of column E (the `X` variable) and then to write to a single dimesion output array `Y`

Pls note that this code retruns values from the cells, whether they are formulae based on constants. It can easily be updated to return formulae by changing

1. `X = rngArea.Value2` to `X = rngArea.Formula`
2. `Y(lngRowTot) = rngArea.Value` to `Y(lngRowTot) = rngArea.Formula`

**Sample Output**

[image: code sample]

**Code**

```
    Sub GetEm()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim rngFinal As Range
    Dim rngArea As Range
    Dim X
    Dim Y
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngRowTot As Long

    'early exit if there are no values
    If Application.CountA(Columns("E")) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Column E has no formulae or constants", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'quickly determine the range of constants and formulae
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng1 = Columns("E").SpecialCells(xlFormulas)
    Set rng2 = Columns("E").SpecialCells(xlConstants)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
        If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
            Set rngFinal = Union(rng1, rng2)
        Else
            Set rngFinal = rng1
        End If
    Else
        Set rngFinal = rng2
    End If

    ReDim Y(1 To 100)

    'Look at each range area (data may not be continuous)
    For Each rngArea In rngFinal.Areas
    'Use variant arrays to popluate a single dimension string array
        If rngArea.Cells.Count > 1 Then
            X = rngArea.Value2
            For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X)
                lngRowTot = lngRowTot + 1
                If lngRowTot Mod 100 = 0 Then ReDim Preserve Y(1 To (UBound(Y) + 100))
                Y(lngRowTot) = X(lngRow, 1)
            Next
        Else
        'handle single cells
            lngRowTot = lngRowTot + 1
            If lngRowTot Mod 100 = 0 Then ReDim Preserve Y(UBound(Y) + 100)
            Y(lngRowTot) = rngArea.Value
        End If
    Next

    'cut down array to require size
    ReDim Preserve Y(1 To lngRowTot)
    MsgBox Join(Y, ", "), , "Your array is"
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice one. When I answered the question, I tried a `array = Columns("E").SpecialCells(xlConstants).Value` which didn't work because it stopped at the first empty value (wanted to avoid any loop). Nice code though :)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check if the cell **is not** empty:

try to change:

```
If IsEmpty(Cells(i, "E")) Then
```

to:

```
If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, "E")) Then
```

Btw, you should use an `Option Explicit` at the begining of your code to *force* the variable declaration. You would then add:

```
Dim i As Integer,
Dim lSize As Long
```

*Note:* I've replaced your `dimX` var by a `lSize` var because `Dim dimX` was making me cry.